# Separating elements in a list but still in order another list

Tags: python, list

I want to separate this list

```
[1000011]
```

and turn it into

```
["1", "0000", "11"]
```

Comment: Based on what are you "splitting"? 1's and 0's? Please show more examples and what code you've already tried

Comment: @OneCricketeer reasonably, I guess on similar characters

Comment: What is the `1000011`?  - is it just an `integer` or something else?  Please confirm.  For some reason, `groupby` just pops ...

Comment: @OneCricketeer im to append the 1's and 0's to a new list but having problems with keeping it all in the same order

Comment: What kinds of problems? What code are you using that is modifying the order? Please [edit] your post to show it

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` has a [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method, which should do exactly what you want.

```
from itertools import groupby

vals = [1000011]
splitVals = []

for val in vals:
    splitVals.extend(''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(str(val)))

print(splitVals)
```

Or, if you want you can compress the `for` loop into one line:

```
splitVals = [''.join(g) for val in vals for k,g in groupby(str(val))]
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw9DoMwDIV3n8IbiVRVRJ25RpeKoZVKcIHYctxKnD4EhPq2970fWW3kdCtlUF6Q7K3GPGekRVgNo/JXXivA71lhh4/QVoXQQ5aZ7H7Sprl@mJKLHgdWrGWkhMdm99Ml7v48c9nU1cz7HkCUkrn/mS9lAw)

Comment: great minds… use itertools :p ->[]

Comment: Great. This is what come to my mind too. +1. It would be nicer to explain the steps/logic little for the uninitiated...  ;-)

Comment: @DanielHao: Most of the magic here is `groupby()` which "returns consecutive keys and groups", exactly what the question was asking.  The rest is just having fun with list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
l = [1000011]

from itertools import groupby

[[''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(str(x))] for x in l]
```

output: `['1', '0000', '11']`

If you have several values in the input list:

input: `l = [1000011, 1221]`

output: `[['1', '0000', '11'], ['1', '22', '1']]`

Comment: I was writing my answer as I saw yours posted!  Looks like we both did the same thing :)

Comment: I like your 2nd code block.  I wasn't sure what to do with multiple values.  I "flattened" them into one list. but i like your suggestion of multiple lists.

Comment: Well, OP's requirements are not clear (maybe there's just one element), anyway as you said the important part is `groupby`, the rest is just looping ;)

Comment: actually I'll only keep that one ;)

Comment: Works perfectly,Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Conor out of curiosity, what is the use case for this?